# Jquery to check if inside element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to add a class to an element if the user has clicked inside it.

All the usual rules apply - "inside" means that it could be inside a child, grandchild etc.

If inside, I need to add a class - if outside the class should be removed.

I've pieced together this example, which works, but as a non-javascript man, I'd appreciate some feedback as to whether it's a reasonable approach, and if it can be improved on - by improved, I refer to jquery/javascript performance.

Any advice appreciated.

```js
$("body").click(function (e) {

    $fs = $(e.target).closest("fieldset.expand");

    if ($fs.length) {
        $fs.addClass("focus");
    }
    else {
        $("fieldset.expand").removeClass("focus");
    }
});
```

```html
<body>
    <fieldset class="expand">
        <input type="text" />
        <input type="text" />
        <input type="text" />
    </fieldset>
</body>
```

Comment: @AlexChar - added typical usage html but its nothing special.

Comment: So basically you want to add the class if user trying to click on any input field inside `fieldset` having `expand` class. If it is true then we can improve the codes? Let me know!

Comment: @DeepakBiswal - yes you got it spot on Deepak.

Comment: @JohnOhara then why don't you bind click
 event with "on"  to that particular div and just add class else just remove it

Comment: Use `focus/blur` events instead to set your logic

Comment: ⇑⇑⇑  sorry, `focusin focusout` events instead, see:  http://jsfiddle.net/3kg7vjpp/2

Comment: @AlexChar - this doesn't work as it needs to. If you click on the button itself, no focus is applied to the parent, only the child. The idea behind the function, is so that it doesn't matter whether the user clicks on the parent, children, padding.

Comment: @JohnOhara I think your last comment was for me, here is updated jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3kg7vjpp/3/

Comment: @A.Wolff - thanks for the code. Still a glitch I'm afraid - it only works with a single child level - my inputs have wrapper, so it doesn't immediately work as is.

Comment: @JohnOhara then just use instead: `$(this).find('*').addBack().is(':focus')`  http://jsfiddle.net/3kg7vjpp/4/

Comment: @A.Wolff - Thanks works great - if you add it as an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Makes your `fieldset` focusable (but not tabbable), using `tabindex` attribute with negative value. Then set your logic using `focusin focusout` events:

```js
$('fieldset.expand').on('focusin focusout', function() {
  $(this).toggleClass('focus', $(this).find('*').addBack().is(':focus'));
});
```

```css
fieldset.focus {
  outline: 0;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<fieldset tabindex="-1" class="expand">
  <input type="text" />
  <input type="text" />
  <input type="text" />
</fieldset>
```